# How to get data from a shared service updated from parent component to show up in child component using angular?

Tags: angular

I have a parentcomponent and a childcomponent. Both share the same service. Clicking on a button on ParentComponent updates an array of objects in SharedService with a new item. When I look on my page, it looks like ChildComponent does not actually update its template that has {{sharedService.listofitems}} with the new entry.

I am using  github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter. My SharedService is the "appState", where I am doign appState.state.listofitems.push({'item':'Apple'}). Link to appState code here: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.service.ts

Using angular 1, I have $scope.$apply(...) Is there a way to get my child component to "refresh" with new data?

```
ParentComponent===
constructor(public appState:AppState) {
  this.appState.set('listofitems', [])
}

buttonClicked() {
    this.appState.state.listofitems.push({'item': 'Apple'})
}
```

ChildComponent Template

```
<span>{{this.listofitems}}</span>
```

ChildComponent TypeScript

```
constructor(public appState:AppState) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.listofitems = this.appState.get('listofitems');
}
```

Comment: how do you read this array in the child component and how do you use it in the template?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter. It has an appState service. In my parent, the function that processes the button click is doing appState.state.listofitems.push({'item': 'Apple'}). appState is the SharedService.

Comment: where did you place your service under 'providers'? make sure it is not placed under child component.

Comment: can you add the relevant code to the question details?

Comment: I thought to use a service in any number of components you have to specify  the service in 'providers'?

Comment: @Maximus Updated OP with relevant code.

Comment: is it `nrgx`? what's `appState`?

Comment: @Rolando i guess you are working with ngrx here.Please look at this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/ngrx) on how to use ngrx. There are multiple ways you can acheive this like event emitters shared services or ngrx . here i guess you are working with ngrx

Comment: beware that don't instantiate the service more that once in your app, because you want to use it like a global variable. So either place the service inside AppComponent (root component) for global access or inside the parent component for children's access only.

Comment: @Maximus I included what appState is https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.service.ts Sample of usage of appState is in the repository too.